# Save and recognize mouse gestures in c#

Tags: c#, mouse, gesture

I have a c#-programm. Now I want to add a mouse gesture-functionality.
A user can make a gesture and save it. When he does it again, some specified action should occur.

Is there somewhere a free codesnippet in c# that does this already? If there isn't how would a good aproach be to recognize and save them?

There should be two functionalities:

1. Save a drawn gesture
2. Recognize a drawn gesture in the saved ones

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a code snippet to me, I doubt you will find code snipets. This sounds like quite complex stuff, snippet might be a wrong choise of words. This would probably need a hole library of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mouse Gestures from CodePlex](http://mousegestures.codeplex.com/) seems to be what you are looking for. I haven't tried it myself, but the source code is available if you need to extend the functionality.

Just make sure to read the [license](http://mousegestures.codeplex.com/license) before publishing or anything like that.

Comment: Thank you, looks good on the first sight. But I have to get into it a bit

Answer (score 1):

There is a Mouse functionality related class: [System.Windows.Input.Mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.aspx)
You can use it.

Comment: Thanks. But I know how to handle a mousedown, mousemove and mouseup-events. But I don't know how to save the values I get as gestures, and how to recognize them again...